# Why is my settings file missing if I copied and pasted my entire project folder?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, android-studio

I copied/pasted my project folder from my desktop to my laptop and installed most of the things needed, like the Android SDK, flutter, and the dart sdk. However, when I try to run my app, it gives an error:

```
Starting Gradle Daemon...
Gradle Daemon started in 2 s 402 ms

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Executing Gradle tasks as part of a build without a settings file is not supported. Make sure that you are executing Gradle from a directory within your Gradle project. Your project should have a 'settings.gradle(.kts)' file in the root directory.
```

Why would this file be missing if I copied the whole project root folder?

Comment: How did you try to build the project? I mean which option did you try?

Comment: @KaushikChandru I hit Shift +F10 (the play button at the top)

Answer (score 0):

In terminal run

```
flutter run
```

In the root directory of the project..

Or if you are using VS Code try

f5 key to start debugging. Or in case of android srudio you should be seeing a play button to run it as a flutter project.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was hitting the play button while the configuration was set to something other than `main.dart`.